# LWJGL: Opening window causes program to crash

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am attempting to make a simple game in Java / LWJGL. I was following a tutorial that was made on windows and I'm using a mac. I copied his code for opening up a window character for character and the program crashed instantly giving me a very long and weird error that probably has something to do with pointers (I don't actually know). Here is the line for creating a window that I used where width and height are defined in the properties:

```
 window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Flappy Bird", NULL, NULL);
```

When I run it on my mac, it gives me this error:

```
2015-10-12 13:18:38.475 java[496:31875] *** Assertion failure in + [NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-1154/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:340
2015-10-12 13:18:38.476 java[496:31875] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
2015-10-12 13:18:38.476 java[496:31875] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98c3003c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9620a76e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98c2fe1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff99f6199b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff99ee364f +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff96ecbb95 -[NSApplication run] + 756
6   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d597974 initializeAppKit + 1332
7   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d597035 _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 37
8   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d59397b glfwCreateWindow + 443
9   ???                                 0x0000000104411eee 0x0 + 4366343918
10  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
11  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
12  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
13  ???                                 0x000000010440685a 0x0 + 4366297178
14  ???                                 0x0000000104406d34 0x0 + 4366298420
)
2015-10-12 13:18:38.477 java[496:31875] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-1154/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:340
2015-10-12 13:18:38.477 java[496:31875] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-10-12 13:18:38.477 java[496:31875] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
2015-10-12 13:18:38.477 java[496:31875] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98c3003c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9620a76e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98c2fe1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff99f6199b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff99ee364f +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff96ecbc41 -[NSApplication run] + 928
6   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d597974 initializeAppKit + 1332
7   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d597035 _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 37
8   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d59397b glfwCreateWindow + 443
9   ???                                 0x0000000104411eee 0x0 + 4366343918
10  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
11  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
12  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
13  ???                                 0x000000010440685a 0x0 + 4366297178
14  ???                                 0x0000000104406d34 0x0 + 4366298420
)
2015-10-12 13:18:38.478 java[496:31875] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98c3003c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9620a76e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98c2fe1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff99f6199b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff99ee364f +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff96ecbc41 -[NSApplication run] + 928
6   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d597974 initializeAppKit + 1332
7   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d597035 _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 37
8   libglfw.dylib                       0x000000010d59397b glfwCreateWindow + 443
9   ???                                 0x0000000104411eee 0x0 + 4366343918
10  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
11  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
12  ???                                 0x0000000104406929 0x0 + 4366297385
13  ???                                 0x000000010440685a 0x0 + 4366297178
14  ???                                 0x0000000104406d34 0x0 + 4366298420
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

A window also pops up that says, "java quit unexpectedly while using the libglfw.dylib plug-in."

Did I install LWJGL wrong or is my code flawed? Thanks for the help!

```
<terminated>
```

Comment: You should not ignore all exceptions. Throw an exception or print a message everywhere you simply return at the moment. You should also set an error callback with [glfwSetErrorCallback](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwSetErrorCallback(org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback)) and run your program with `-Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true`.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you run your application with jvm flag `-XstartOnFirstThread`. Although this seems to be specifically about OSX. [See this SO Answer what this argument means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149634/what-does-the-xstartonfirstthread-vm-argument-do-mean)

Comment: This saved my day and works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using LWJGL 3 I recommend you to follow Oskar's video tutorial for setting your project and display.

[Workspace setting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDV9UXTk4Qo)

[Display tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzDZIN1eSGQ)

And try to use `MemoryUtil.NULL` instead of standard `null` in your glfwCreateWindow call.

Comment: `MemoryUtil.NULL` is a long while `null` is an object, so you can't "use it instead".